# Next.js 13 - Video Tag not working on mobile

Tags: reactjs, video, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I am using Next 13 with the app directory, and I have a background video on the home screen. It plays well on desktop, but on mobile browsers, the video doesn't play. On the computer it works at any size, even when shrinking down the browser, but on mobile, I am having issues playing the video in all browsers I have tried (Brave, Firefox Focus, Red Browser, Neeva and Safari)
Instead of playing the video, the browser stays on the first frame.

The code looks like this:

```
export default async function Page() {
  return (
    <section className="relative h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-center bg-ac_color-dark text-ac_color-lightgold py-0 px-3">
      <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full overflow-hidden">
      <video
          className="min-w-full h-[90vh] absolute object-cover z-2 opacity-50"
          src="/ac_movie.mp4"
          autoPlay
          muted
          loop
        >
        </video>
        
      </div>
    </section>
    );
}
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with this code:

```
<video
          
        controls
        width="250"
        className="w-2/3 h-full aspect-square object-cover rounded-xl "
    >
          <source src={product.video} type="video/webm" />
  </video>
```

I served the videos from cloudinary which stores the videos in `mp4` format. so i changed the type and it works now:

```
  <source src={product.video} type="video/mp4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `playsInline` attribute on the video tag, which will allow it to play on mobile without going to fullscreen.

```
      <video
          src="..."
          autoPlay
          muted
          loop
          playsInline
        >
        </video>
```

You can read about [the policy here](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/).

Answer (score -1):

For the video tag, the source is added with the source tag e.g

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: The `src` attribute is also valid when you only have one version of the video.